# Wanting to compare two data frames to check if username and password are correct from the data saved in my excel file, using pandas only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make a login page with Tkinter, and pandas only, trying to store all the data in excel file and am having trouble with reading the excel file.

```py
import pandas as pd

def USPchecker():# method name
        obt_Username = UsrInp.get() # storring input from user for username
        obt_Password = PassInp.get() # storring password from user

        # print(File)

        for row in File.iterrows():
            df2 = pd.DataFrame(row)
            df2.sort_index(inplace=True)
            print(df2)

            dataFUN = {'USERNAME': obt_Username, 'PASSWORD': obt_Password}
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(dataFUN, index=[NONE])
            df1.sort_index(inplace=True)
            print(df1)

            if df1.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True) == df2.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True):
                report_window()
            else:
                messagebox.showerr("DOXC", "wrong username or password")
```

Comment: it appears as though part of the code is missing so a lot ofthe items are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are storing the obt data in a dataframe.
The below function will return True or False regarding the obt fields:

```
def check_login(df2, obt_Username, obt_Password):
    df = df2[df2['username']==obt_Username] & df2['password']==obt_Password]
    if len(df) > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```